# Inline Lambda variable vs Inline function vs Inline template function with automatic type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, inline, c++20

Suppose I want declare an inline function which will take an argument of arbitrary type.
I think it can be done by the following ways.

```cpp
//////
inline auto const myfunc = [&](const auto& val){return something(val);};
//////
inline auto myfunc(const auto& val)
{
    return something(val);
}
//////
template<class T>
inline T myfunc(const T& val)
{
    return something(val);    
}
```

So I have several questions.

1. Is there any error in my definitions, are these definitions supported?
2. Does any of these definitions have any advantage over another, and if yes, what advantages?
3. Which one of these definitions is better in terms of code quality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please one question per question. 1) you could answer by trying to compile it

Comment: You can’t possibly have an `inline` variable initialized directly with a lambda with a (non-init-) capture (which can appear only inside a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all 3 define something sightly different. Hence, answer to 2 is: Choose the one that does what you want. 1) I'll levave to you, because you can easily try them out to see if they compile. 3) isn't that relevant, because choosing between them is a matter of what you actually need, not of style.

```
inline auto const myfunc = [&](const auto& val){return something(val);};
```

The lambda `myfunc` is of some unnamed type with a templated `operator()`. `myfunc` itself is not templated. You can pass `myfunc` to other functions, because it is an object. You cannot do that easily with the other two.

The difference between

```
inline auto myfunc(const auto& val)
{
    return something(val);
}
```

and

```
template<class T>
inline T myfunc(const T& val)
{
    return something(val);    
}
```

is the return type. With the second, the return type is `T`. `T` is either deduced from the paramter or you specify it explicitly and then it can be different from the parameter passed, as long as the parameter can convert to `const T&`. Hence the first is more similar to the lambda (more precisely, to its `operator()`), because the return type is deduced from `something(val)`, though the lambda additionally captures via `&`. You cannot do that easily with a function.

Comment: I have a concern regarding to passing the `struct` as a function parameter. As far as it is marked as `inline`, it should be expanded in a line in compile time(as it is stated in [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-functions-cpp/#:~:text=Inline%20function%20is%20a%20function,C%2B%2B%20compiler%20at%20compile%20time.) article), so may that cause any complications while passing it as an argument?

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan that article is terribly misleading. You can read eg here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline about the actual meaning of "inline function". In ancient times `inline` was to tell the compiler that function calls should be inlined, but thats not the case anymore. Confusingly the keyword and most of its meaning is still the same, but it is *not* to decide whether calls should be inlined by the compiler as that article suggests.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan for example, since c++17: "Because the meaning of the keyword inline for functions came to mean "multiple definitions are permitted" rather than "inlining is preferred", that meaning was extended to variables. "

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan in general I cannot recommend geeksforgeeks as a resource for learning C++. Unfortunately such misinformation is the rule rather than an exception on that site

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Note that C++20 modules may restore some of the meaning of `inline` in that there are (non-binding) ABI reasons to avoid inlining non-`inline` functions and that there is no need for inline variables.